# phpexcel showing zero rows even when 150 rows are present in the excel file

Tags: php, excel, phpexcelreader

I am using [PHPexcelReader](http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpexcelreader/) for importing excel files.everything is working fine when maxcol value i give as 92 but when the maxcolvalue is 206,the numver of rows of excel file is showing 0 even when there are 150 rows.

```
 $maxcols=206
 echo $data->sheets[0]['numCols']."numcol<br>";//showing 206,its correct
 echo $data->sheets[0]['numRows'];//showing 0,incorrect there are 150 rows
 print_r($data->sheets[0]['cells']);//showing correctly all the data
 echo $maxcols."<br>";

  if($data->sheets[0]['numCols'] >= $maxcols)
      { 
   $total_rows=$data->sheets[0]['numRows']-1;

     if($total_rows > 0)
     {
          //my codes
      }
   }
```

Reader.php code:

```
<?php


define('NUM_BIG_BLOCK_DEPOT_BLOCKS_POS', 0x2c);
define('SMALL_BLOCK_DEPOT_BLOCK_POS', 0x3c);
define('ROOT_START_BLOCK_POS', 0x30);
define('BIG_BLOCK_SIZE', 0x200);
define('SMALL_BLOCK_SIZE', 0x40);
define('EXTENSION_BLOCK_POS', 0x44);
define('NUM_EXTENSION_BLOCK_POS', 0x48);
define('PROPERTY_STORAGE_BLOCK_SIZE', 0x80);
define('BIG_BLOCK_DEPOT_BLOCKS_POS', 0x4c);
define('SMALL_BLOCK_THRESHOLD', 0x1000);
// property storage offsets
define('SIZE_OF_NAME_POS', 0x40);
define('TYPE_POS', 0x42);
define('START_BLOCK_POS', 0x74);
define('SIZE_POS', 0x78);
define('IDENTIFIER_OLE', pack("CCCCCCCC",0xd0,0xcf,0x11,0xe0,0xa1,0xb1,0x1a,0xe1));




define('SPREADSHEET_EXCEL_READER_BIFF8',             0x600);
define('SPREADSHEET_EXCEL_READER_BIFF7',             0x500);
define('SPREADSHEET_EXCEL_READER_WORKBOOKGLOBALS',   0x5);
define('SPREADSHEET_EXCEL_READER_WORKSHEET',         0x10);
define('SPREADSHEET_EXCEL_READER_TYPE_BOF',       0x809);
define('SPREADSHEET_EXCEL_READER_TYPE_EOF',       0x0a);
define('SPREADSHEET_EXCEL_READER_TYPE_BOUNDSHEET',   0x85);
define('SPREADSHEET_EXCEL_READER_TYPE_DIMENSION',   0x200);
define('SPREADSHEET_EXCEL_READER_TYPE_ROW',       0x208);
define('SPREADSHEET_EXCEL_READER_TYPE_DBCELL',     0xd7);
define('SPREADSHEET_EXCEL_READER_TYPE_FILEPASS',     0x2f);
define('SPREADSHEET_EXCEL_READER_TYPE_NOTE',         0x1c);
define('SPREADSHEET_EXCEL_READER_TYPE_TXO',       0x1b6);
define('SPREADSHEET_EXCEL_READER_TYPE_RK',         0x7e);
define('SPREADSHEET_EXCEL_READER_TYPE_RK2',       0x27e);
define('SPREADSHEET_EXCEL_READER_TYPE_MULRK',       0xbd);
define('SPREADSHEET_EXCEL_READER_TYPE_MULBLANK',     0xbe);
define('SPREADSHEET_EXCEL_READER_TYPE_INDEX',       0x20b);
define('SPREADSHEET_EXCEL_READER_TYPE_SST',       0xfc);
define('SPREADSHEET_EXCEL_READER_TYPE_EXTSST',     0xff);
define('SPREADSHEET_EXCEL_READER_TYPE_CONTINUE',     0x3c);
define('SPREADSHEET_EXCEL_READER_TYPE_LABEL',       0x204);
define('SPREADSHEET_EXCEL_READER_TYPE_LABELSST',     0xfd);
define('SPREADSHEET_EXCEL_READER_TYPE_NUMBER',     0x203);
define('SPREADSHEET_EXCEL_READER_TYPE_NAME',         0x18);
define('SPREADSHEET_EXCEL_READER_TYPE_ARRAY',       0x221);
define('SPREADSHEET_EXCEL_READER_TYPE_STRING',     0x207);
define('SPREADSHEET_EXCEL_READER_TYPE_FORMULA',   0x406);
define('SPREADSHEET_EXCEL_READER_TYPE_FORMULA2',     0x6);
define('SPREADSHEET_EXCEL_READER_TYPE_FORMAT',     0x41e);
define('SPREADSHEET_EXCEL_READER_TYPE_XF',         0xe0);
define('SPREADSHEET_EXCEL_READER_TYPE_BOOLERR',   0x205);
define('SPREADSHEET_EXCEL_READER_TYPE_FONT',      0x0031);
define('SPREADSHEET_EXCEL_READER_TYPE_PALETTE',   0x0092);
define('SPREADSHEET_EXCEL_READER_TYPE_UNKNOWN',   0xffff);
define('SPREADSHEET_EXCEL_READER_TYPE_NINETEENFOUR', 0x22);
define('SPREADSHEET_EXCEL_READER_TYPE_MERGEDCELLS',  0xE5);
define('SPREADSHEET_EXCEL_READER_UTCOFFSETDAYS' ,   25569);
define('SPREADSHEET_EXCEL_READER_UTCOFFSETDAYS1904', 24107);
define('SPREADSHEET_EXCEL_READER_MSINADAY',       86400);
define('SPREADSHEET_EXCEL_READER_TYPE_HYPER',        0x01b8);
define('SPREADSHEET_EXCEL_READER_TYPE_COLINFO',      0x7d);
define('SPREADSHEET_EXCEL_READER_TYPE_DEFCOLWIDTH',  0x55);
define('SPREADSHEET_EXCEL_READER_TYPE_STANDARDWIDTH', 0x99);
define('SPREADSHEET_EXCEL_READER_DEF_NUM_FORMAT',   "%s");


/*
* Main Class
*/
class Spreadsheet_Excel_Reader {

    // MK: Added to make data retrieval easier
    var $colnames = array();
    var $colindexes = array();
    var $standardColWidth = 0;
    var $defaultColWidth = 0;

    function myHex($d) {
        if ($d < 16) return "0" . dechex($d);
        return dechex($d);
    }

    function dumpHexData($data, $pos, $length) {
        $info = "";
        for ($i = 0; $i <= $length; $i++) {
            $info .= ($i==0?"":" ") . $this->myHex(ord($data[$pos + $i])) . (ord($data[$pos + $i])>31? "[" . $data[$pos + $i] . "]":'');
        }
        return $info;
    }

    function getCol($col) {
        if (is_string($col)) {
            $col = strtolower($col);
            if (array_key_exists($col,$this->colnames)) {
                $col = $this->colnames[$col];
            }
        }
        return $col;
    }

    // PUBLIC API FUNCTIONS
    // --------------------

    function val($row,$col,$sheet=0) {
        $col = $this->getCol($col);
        if (array_key_exists($row,$this->sheets[$sheet]['cells']) && array_key_exists($col,$this->sheets[$sheet]['cells'][$row])) {
            return $this->sheets[$sheet]['cells'][$row][$col];
        }
        return "";
    }
    function value($row,$col,$sheet=0) {
        return $this->val($row,$col,$sheet);
    }
    function info($row,$col,$type='',$sheet=0) {
        $col = $this->getCol($col);
        if (array_key_exists('cellsInfo',$this->sheets[$sheet])
                && array_key_exists($row,$this->sheets[$sheet]['cellsInfo'])
                && array_key_exists($col,$this->sheets[$sheet]['cellsInfo'][$row])
                && array_key_exists($type,$this->sheets[$sheet]['cellsInfo'][$row][$col])) {
            return $this->sheets[$sheet]['cellsInfo'][$row][$col][$type];
        }
        return "";
    }
    function type($row,$col,$sheet=0) {
        return $this->info($row,$col,'type',$sheet);
    }
    function raw($row,$col,$sheet=0) {
        return $this->info($row,$col,'raw',$sheet);
    }
    function rowspan($row,$col,$sheet=0) {
        $val = $this->info($row,$col,'rowspan',$sheet);
        if ($val=="") { return 1; }
        return $val;
    }
    function colspan($row,$col,$sheet=0) {
        $val = $this->info($row,$col,'colspan',$sheet);
        if ($val=="") { return 1; }
        return $val;
    }
    function hyperlink($row,$col,$sheet=0) {
        $link = $this->sheets[$sheet]['cellsInfo'][$row][$col]['hyperlink'];
        if ($link) {
            return $link['link'];
        }
        return '';
    }
    function rowcount($sheet=0) {
        return $this->sheets[$sheet]['numRows'];
    }
    function colcount($sheet=0) {
        return $this->sheets[$sheet]['numCols'];
    }
    function colwidth($col,$sheet=0) {
        // Col width is actually the width of the number 0. So we have to estimate and come close
        return $this->colInfo[$sheet][$col]['width']/9142*200; 
    }
    function colhidden($col,$sheet=0) {
        return !!$this->colInfo[$sheet][$col]['hidden'];
    }
    function rowheight($row,$sheet=0) {
        return $this->rowInfo[$sheet][$row]['height'];
    }
    function rowhidden($row,$sheet=0) {
        return !!$this->rowInfo[$sheet][$row]['hidden'];
    }




    // CELL (XF) PROPERTIES
    // ====================
    function xfRecord($row,$col,$sheet=0) {
        $xfIndex = $this->info($row,$col,'xfIndex',$sheet);
        if ($xfIndex!="") {
            return $this->xfRecords[$xfIndex];
        }
        return null;
    }
    function xfProperty($row,$col,$sheet,$prop) {
        $xfRecord = $this->xfRecord($row,$col,$sheet);
        if ($xfRecord!=null) {
            return $xfRecord[$prop];
        }
        return "";
    }


    // DUMP AN HTML TABLE OF THE ENTIRE XLS DATA
    // =========================================
    function dump($row_numbers=false,$col_letters=false,$sheet=0,$table_class='excel') {
        $out = "<table class=\"$table_class\" cellspacing=0>";
        if ($col_letters) {
            $out .= "<thead>\n\t<tr>";
            if ($row_numbers) {
                $out .= "\n\t\t<th>&nbsp</th>";
            }
            for($i=1;$i<=$this->colcount($sheet);$i++) {
                $style = "width:" . ($this->colwidth($i,$sheet)*1) . "px;";
                if ($this->colhidden($i,$sheet)) {
                    $style .= "display:none;";
                }
                $out .= "\n\t\t<th style=\"$style\">" . strtoupper($this->colindexes[$i]) . "</th>";
            }
            $out .= "</tr></thead>\n";
        }

        $out .= "<tbody>\n";
        for($row=1;$row<=$this->rowcount($sheet);$row++) {
            $rowheight = $this->rowheight($row,$sheet);
            $style = "height:" . ($rowheight*(4/3)) . "px;";
            if ($this->rowhidden($row,$sheet)) {
                $style .= "display:none;";
            }
            $out .= "\n\t<tr style=\"$style\">";
            if ($row_numbers) {
                $out .= "\n\t\t<th>$row</th>";
            }
            for($col=1;$col<=$this->colcount($sheet);$col++) {
                // Account for Rowspans/Colspans
                $rowspan = $this->rowspan($row,$col,$sheet);
                $colspan = $this->colspan($row,$col,$sheet);
                for($i=0;$i<$rowspan;$i++) {
                    for($j=0;$j<$colspan;$j++) {
                        if ($i>0 || $j>0) {
                            $this->sheets[$sheet]['cellsInfo'][$row+$i][$col+$j]['dontprint']=1;
                        }
                    }
                }
                if(!$this->sheets[$sheet]['cellsInfo'][$row][$col]['dontprint']) {
                    $style = $this->style($row,$col,$sheet);
                    if ($this->colhidden($col,$sheet)) {
                        $style .= "display:none;";
                    }
                    $out .= "\n\t\t<td style=\"$style\"" . ($colspan > 1?" colspan=$colspan":"") . ($rowspan > 1?" rowspan=$rowspan":"") . ">";
                    $val = $this->val($row,$col,$sheet);
                    if ($val=='') { $val="&nbsp;"; }
                    else { 
                        $val = htmlentities($val); 
                        $link = $this->hyperlink($row,$col,$sheet);
                        if ($link!='') {
                            $val = "<a href=\"$link\">$val</a>";
                        }
                    }
                    $out .= "<nobr>".nl2br($val)."</nobr>";
                    $out .= "</td>";
                }
            }
            $out .= "</tr>\n";
        }
        $out .= "</tbody></table>";
        return $out;
    }

    // --------------
    // END PUBLIC API


    var $boundsheets = array();
    var $formatRecords = array();
    var $fontRecords = array();
    var $xfRecords = array();
    var $colInfo = array();
    var $rowInfo = array();

    var $sst = array();
    var $sheets = array();

    var $data;
    var $_ole;
    var $_defaultEncoding = "UTF-8";
    var $_defaultFormat = SPREADSHEET_EXCEL_READER_DEF_NUM_FORMAT;
    var $_columnsFormat = array();
    var $_rowoffset = 1;
    var $_coloffset = 1;

    /**
     * List of default date formats used by Excel
     */
    var $dateFormats = array (
        0xe => "m/d/Y",
        0xf => "M-d-Y",
        0x10 => "d-M",
        0x11 => "M-Y",
        0x12 => "h:i a",
        0x13 => "h:i:s a",
        0x14 => "H:i",
        0x15 => "H:i:s",
        0x16 => "d/m/Y H:i",
        0x2d => "i:s",
        0x2e => "H:i:s",
        0x2f => "i:s.S"
    );

    /**
     * Default number formats used by Excel
     */

     * Read the spreadsheet file using OLE, then parse
     */
    function read($sFileName) {
        $res = $this->_ole->read($sFileName);

        // oops, something goes wrong (Darko Miljanovic)
        if($res === false) {
            // check error code
            if($this->_ole->error == 1) {
                // bad file
                die('The filename ' . $sFileName . ' is not readable');
            }
            // check other error codes here (eg bad fileformat, etc...)
        }
        $this->data = $this->_ole->getWorkBook();
        $this->_parse();
    }

    /**
     * Parse a workbook
     *
     * @access private
     * @return bool
     */
    function _parse() {
        $pos = 0;
        $data = $this->data;

        $code = v($data,$pos);
        $length = v($data,$pos+2);
        $version = v($data,$pos+4);
        $substreamType = v($data,$pos+6);

        $this->version = $version;

        if (($version != SPREADSHEET_EXCEL_READER_BIFF8) &&
            ($version != SPREADSHEET_EXCEL_READER_BIFF7)) {
            return false;
        }

        if ($substreamType != SPREADSHEET_EXCEL_READER_WORKBOOKGLOBALS){
            return false;
        }

        $pos += $length + 4;

        $code = v($data,$pos);
        $length = v($data,$pos+2);

        while ($code != SPREADSHEET_EXCEL_READER_TYPE_EOF) {
            switch ($code) {
                case SPREADSHEET_EXCEL_READER_TYPE_SST:
                    $spos = $pos + 4;
                    $limitpos = $spos + $length;
                    $uniqueStrings = $this->_GetInt4d($data, $spos+4);
                    $spos += 8;
                    for ($i = 0; $i < $uniqueStrings; $i++) {
                        // Read in the number of characters
                        if ($spos == $limitpos) {
                            $opcode = v($data,$spos);
                            $conlength = v($data,$spos+2);
                            if ($opcode != 0x3c) {
                                return -1;
                            }
                            $spos += 4;
                            $limitpos = $spos + $conlength;
                        }
                        $numChars = ord($data[$spos]) | (ord($data[$spos+1]) << 8);
                        $spos += 2;
                        $optionFlags = ord($data[$spos]);
                        $spos++;
                        $asciiEncoding = (($optionFlags & 0x01) == 0) ;
                        $extendedString = ( ($optionFlags & 0x04) != 0);

                        // See if string contains formatting information
                        $richString = ( ($optionFlags & 0x08) != 0);

                        if ($richString) {
                            // Read in the crun
                            $formattingRuns = v($data,$spos);
                            $spos += 2;
                        }

                        if ($extendedString) {
                            // Read in cchExtRst
                            $extendedRunLength = $this->_GetInt4d($data, $spos);
                            $spos += 4;
                        }

                        $len = ($asciiEncoding)? $numChars : $numChars*2;
                        if ($spos + $len < $limitpos) {
                            $retstr = substr($data, $spos, $len);
                            $spos += $len;
                        }
                        else{
                            // found countinue
                            $retstr = substr($data, $spos, $limitpos - $spos);
                            $bytesRead = $limitpos - $spos;
                            $charsLeft = $numChars - (($asciiEncoding) ? $bytesRead : ($bytesRead / 2));
                            $spos = $limitpos;

                            while ($charsLeft > 0){
                                $opcode = v($data,$spos);
                                $conlength = v($data,$spos+2);
                                if ($opcode != 0x3c) {
                                    return -1;
                                }
                                $spos += 4;
                                $limitpos = $spos + $conlength;
                                $option = ord($data[$spos]);
                                $spos += 1;
                                if ($asciiEncoding && ($option == 0)) {
                                    $len = min($charsLeft, $limitpos - $spos); // min($charsLeft, $conlength);
                                    $retstr .= substr($data, $spos, $len);
                                    $charsLeft -= $len;
                                    $asciiEncoding = true;
                                }
                                elseif (!$asciiEncoding && ($option != 0)) {
                                    $len = min($charsLeft * 2, $limitpos - $spos); // min($charsLeft, $conlength);
                                    $retstr .= substr($data, $spos, $len);
                                    $charsLeft -= $len/2;
                                    $asciiEncoding = false;
                                }
                                elseif (!$asciiEncoding && ($option == 0)) {
                                    // Bummer - the string starts off as Unicode, but after the
                                    // continuation it is in straightforward ASCII encoding
                                    $len = min($charsLeft, $limitpos - $spos); // min($charsLeft, $conlength);
                                    for ($j = 0; $j < $len; $j++) {
                                        $retstr .= $data[$spos + $j].chr(0);
                                    }
                                    $charsLeft -= $len;
                                    $asciiEncoding = false;
                                }
                                else{
                                    $newstr = '';
                                    for ($j = 0; $j < strlen($retstr); $j++) {
                                        $newstr = $retstr[$j].chr(0);
                                    }
                                    $retstr = $newstr;
                                    $len = min($charsLeft * 2, $limitpos - $spos); // min($charsLeft, $conlength);
                                    $retstr .= substr($data, $spos, $len);
                                    $charsLeft -= $len/2;
                                    $asciiEncoding = false;
                                }
                                $spos += $len;
                            }
                        }
                        $retstr = ($asciiEncoding) ? $retstr : $this->_encodeUTF16($retstr);

                        if ($richString){
                            $spos += 4 * $formattingRuns;
                        }

                        // For extended strings, skip over the extended string data
                        if ($extendedString) {
                            $spos += $extendedRunLength;
                        }
                        $this->sst[]=$retstr;
                    }
                    break;
                case SPREADSHEET_EXCEL_READER_TYPE_FILEPASS:
                    return false;
                    break;
                case SPREADSHEET_EXCEL_READER_TYPE_NAME:
                    break;
                case SPREADSHEET_EXCEL_READER_TYPE_FORMAT:
                    $indexCode = v($data,$pos+4);
                    if ($version == SPREADSHEET_EXCEL_READER_BIFF8) {
                        $numchars = v($data,$pos+6);
                        if (ord($data[$pos+8]) == 0){
                            $formatString = substr($data, $pos+9, $numchars);
                        } else {
                            $formatString = substr($data, $pos+9, $numchars*2);
                        }
                    } else {
                        $numchars = ord($data[$pos+6]);
                        $formatString = substr($data, $pos+7, $numchars*2);
                    }
                    $this->formatRecords[$indexCode] = $formatString;
                    break;

    }

}

?>
```

what i am missing?or what i should do to resolve issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is the output of this part  `$maxcols=92
 echo $data->sheets[0]['numCols']."numcol<br>";//showing 206,its correct
 echo $data->sheets[0]['numRows'];//showing 0,incorrect there are 150 rows
 print_r($data->sheets[0]['cells']);//showing correctly all the data
 echo $maxcols."<br>";` and what is out put of this  `$maxcols=206
 echo $data->sheets[0]['numCols']."numcol<br>";//showing 206,its correct
 echo $data->sheets[0]['numRows'];//showing 0,incorrect there are 150 rows
 print_r($data->sheets[0]['cells']);//showing correctly all the data
 echo $maxcols."<br>";`

Comment: @noobie-php thanks for the response,can you please elaborate which part output you want because the above code you wrote looks messy

Comment: i simply want output with `$maxcols=206 and then $maxcols=92;
 echo $data->sheets[0]['numCols']."numcol<br>";//showing 206,its correct
 echo $data->sheets[0]['numRows'];//showing 0,incorrect there are 150 rows
 print_r($data->sheets[0]['cells']);//showing correctly all the data
 echo $maxcols."<br>";`

Comment: Is this actually PHPExcel? It looks more like PEAR Spreadsheet Excel Reader!

Comment: @noobie-php echo $data->sheets[0]['numCols'] will display the result irrespective of the maxcol value

Comment: @MarkBaker thanks for the response ,yes i am using pHPexcel only ,i just verified that after your comment :)

Comment: In that case, please show some PHPExcel code, because PHPExcel doesn't generate any array of sheets with a 'numcols' or 'cells' entries.... so there must be some additional code that is generating that array from the PHPExcel data

Comment: the confusing thing for me, me mate is how can you get 206 `echo $data->sheets[0]['numCols']."numcol<br>";//showing 206,its correct` coz you are explicitly defining it in some other variable and you are not using it any where in the echoed lines

Comment: @MarkBaker sorry i am using phpexcelreader.http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpexcelreader/ i posted some of the code in my answer.